# How can I allow the Current User to have permissions/views tied to their Direct Reports and Manager relationships?

Tags: google-app-maker

In a handful of circumstances, I'd like to allow the Current User to be able view a list of records filtered by Owners of each record that are Direct Reports that they manage or even by the Manager they report to via our global directory.

I'm comfortable making a new Datasource for CurrentUser in a Directory model. However, I'm tripping over myself trying to find the best way to match an Ownership (email) field from a record, with an array of the direct reports associated with the current user.

A specific example would be on the Travel Approval template. The table on the Dashboard page has a filter for "My Requests | All" and I'd love to add a third option for "Direct Report Requests".

My assumption is that I would adjust the onClick event to filter results accordingly:

```
widget.datasource.query.pageIndex = 1;
widget.datasource.query.filters.Owner._equals = app.user.email;
widget.datasource.query.filters.Owner._in = null;
widget.datasource.load();
updateUrlForDashboard();
```

That's one small example, but more importantly, I'd like to get a better understanding of how best to reference/store those additional relationships about the Current User.

Ideally, a current user is able to have greater ability to manage (approve/deny/comment on) resources tied to their Direct Reports and generate records that provide a similar level of control to the Users that Manage them.

I'm not sure if that's best handle by some use of Roles or another approach. Any advice on how best to plan out that kind of setup would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

funny thing ... I had the same question a couple of months ago. I think you will find Pavel's solution on this very interesting. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506812/adaptive-user-management).